# Regular expression to parse SOAP response

Tags: regex, xml, soap, response

I found several solutions for converting SOAP response into a object, but none of them work. I get my soap response as an xml string, e.g.:

```
 $response = '
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://xxx.company.com" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:DataResponse>
          <DataReturn xsi:type="ns1:OutXT">
            <Errors SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:Errors[12]" xsi:type="ns1:ErrorsArray">
              <item xsi:type="ns1:Errors">
                <ErrorItem xsi:type="xsd:string">Access</ErrorItem>
                <DescErrors xsi:type="xsd:string">User not found</DescErrors>
              </item>
              <item xsi:type="ns1:Errors">
                <ErrorItem xsi:type="xsd:string">Client check</ErrorItem>
                <DescErrors xsi:type="xsd:string">Report 85 completed</DescErrors>
              </item>
            </Errors>
            <ClientCategory xsi:type="xsd:string">A</ClientCategory>
            <Premium xsi:type="ns1:Premium">
              <Price xsi:type="xsd:int">2509</Price>
              <Coef xsi:type="xsd:float">4.558</Coef>
              <Discount xsi:type="xsd:int">35</Discount>
            </Premium>
            <Sample xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Sample>
            <Status xsi:type="xsd:string">OK</Status>
          </DataReturn>
        </ns1:DataResponse>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
```

And I need to get rid of all the namespaces including the colon and all the attributes so the outcome in this case would be:

```
<Envelope>
 <Body>
    <DataResponse>
      <DataReturn>
        <Errors>
          <item>
            <ErrorItem>Access</ErrorItem>
            <DescErrors>User not found</DescErrors>
          </item>
          <item>
            <ErrorItem>Client check</ErrorItem>
            <DescErrors>Report 85 completed</DescErrors>
          </item>
        </Errors>
        <ClientCategory>A</ClientCategory>
        <Premium>
          <Price>2509</Price>
          <Coef>4.558</Coef>
          <Discount>35</Discount>
        </Premium>
        <Sample>0</Sample>
        <Status>OK</Status>
      </DataReturn>
    </DataResponse>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I found some regular expression that allegedly does that job but it simply doesn't work either:

```
$response = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $response);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: You shouldn't use regex for this.

Comment: Why I've tried everything and it always ends up with an error..

Comment: It's not duplicate.. I don't know what solution I should use..

Comment: Show what you tried with the parser, include the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could replace the matches of this expression with an empty string:

```
(((?<=<\/)|(?<=<))[^\/\s]*?:|\s?[^\s]+=".*?")
```

See this [in action at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LzIqiq/5)

### Explanation

This Expression matches

1. `(?<=<)|(?<=<\/))[^\/\s]*?:` Namespaces from starting and closing xml-tags (everythis after `<` or `</` until inclusive `:`)
2. `\s?[^\s]+=".*?"` basically all xml-attributes and their prepending whitespace

Comment: You edited your answer but it seems that the original version was working.. This second one doesn't work..

Comment: the expression is the same, i just removed surrounding braces

Comment: you should check if you really need the surounding braces, they could slow the expression down a lot btw.

Comment: Wait, it doesn't work!! It deletes \ in closing tags as well. </SOAP-ENV:Envelope> converts to <Envelope> instead of </Envelope>

Comment: oh, right, then we should exclude that ;) done, see my edit

Comment: glad i could help